# Finding a cycle in a directed graph, however...

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Say we have some directed graph, G. Every now and then, I can add either: a single arc from an existing vertex to another existing vertex (but no self-loops), add one new vertex with an arc to an existing vertex or add two new vertices joined by an arc. Let's call this an iteration.

For each iteration, is it possible to find out if a new arc added, has formed a cycle in the graph, in constant time? Or at least faster than I have done below? I will consider use of Hash tables to be constant. For now, there is no constraint on space complexity.

The best I have come up with so far is: each time a new arc (but not vertex) is added, perform a depth first search from the vertex at the 'head' of the new arc. If the vertex at the tail-end is found, then we have a new cycle. I'm wondering if there's a better way, maybe using hash tables or adjacency matrices?

Anyone is welcome to have a shot at it, any insight or discussion will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try the Disjoint set data structure?